# Unity3d android apk file becomes huge without any scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, game-engine

My game size became huge suddenly. For determining the problem I deleted all the scenes form project window and let the Unity build the empty apk. But the apk becomes 87mb without any scene! **I surprised what did happened or what Unity loading while there is no scene at all!**

Comment: Check the Editor Log (button in top-right of Console window), after building.

Comment: My guess is that it is something in a Resources folder.

Comment: Check compression on your sprites. Unity reacks them on export and 500k image could easily become 2 megs. As Milad mentioned - inspect bottom of Build log, there will be a list of all exported objects and their sizes

Answer (score 0):

from what I've experienced unity has a tendency to package any imports into your final build. so any libraries or packages you told it to import when you created get packaged whether you use the assets in them or not. i've only used unity to build for the pc platform but this is what i've seen when doing benchmarks against empty builds. so be very careful what you import and only import exactly what you need.